# Why do I need to include the same includes in all my source files?

Tags: c++

I have been battling with this on and off for a number of years and each time I think I've cracked it, it comes back to bite me. Let me try and explain what I'm concerned about as such don't properly understand by using the following example;

I have three files, **main.cpp**, **other.h** and **other.cpp** as below;

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "other.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout<<"hello from main...\n";
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

other.h

```
#ifndef OTHER_H
#define OTHER_H

void test();

#endif /* OTHER_H */
```

other.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

void test()
{
    std::cout<<"hello from other\n";
}
```

Now, the three files as they are above, compile and run and produce just the two lines of text.

My question is, **why do I need to include `<iostream>` in other.cpp?**

Naturally, my scenario's are slightly more complex than this example, but it leads me on many occasions to importing or including the same header files over and over again when I would have thought, the import or include would simply be expanded at the point of import or include, and so long as in the example above, `<iostream>` had been included before anything that wishes to use it, then that would be ok.

Now, if I remove **other.cpp** completely and modify **other.h** to actually include the function, this also compiles and runs, and I guess this is where I get even more confused. So with main remaining untouched as above, and **other.h** now looking like this:

other.h

```
#ifndef OTHER_H
#define OTHER_H

void test()
{
    std::cout<<"hello from other\n";
}

#endif /* OTHER_H */
```

This works without including `<iostream>`, yet the former doesn't, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Every .cpp file is a "separate translation unit", the compiler starts from scratch before it begins translating the file.  So needs a declaration for everything it uses.  It works by accident for the .h file, #included by a translation unit that already had an include for iostream.  Smile upside down if the include order is wrong, that's ten minutes of your life you'll never get back.  Fwiw, this is why the "precompiled headers" feature is popular.

Comment: Think of a *.h file as an interface. it exposes what functions and variables exist so they can be called in your cpp file. The definition *.cpp file then contains the actual definition.

Comment: I advice you to include other.h to some another cpp file that doesn't include iostream at all.

Answer (score 2):

Every `.cpp` file is usually compiled separately. Also, an `#include` works by injecting another file's content at that line.

That being said, if you add your `.cpp` code to the `.h`, your main ends up looking like this:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#ifndef OTHER_H
#define OTHER_H

void test()
{
    std::cout<<"hello from other\n";
}

#endif /* OTHER_H */

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout<<"hello from main...\n";
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, `<iostream>` is actually included before the use of `cout`.

In your first example, your `.cpp` doesn't include `<iostream>` anywhere before the use of `cout`.

This doesn't mean you should add the code to the `.h` file. You should instead add the includes you need in every `.cpp`/`.h` file, and only if you need it in that file.

Comment: While what you say in the last line is true,  programmers often whine if they find that - whenever they include header A - their source files don't compile unless they also include header B.   In such cases, although not technically necessary, it may be appropriate for header A to include header B - because, even if header A itself doesn't need header B, source files that include header A do.

Comment: @Peter I can't think in any example of the scenario you describe. Do you have one for me to see? If a header A requires another header B for it to work (just a header, not linking-related), I think it may be generally "wrong", or a bad practice. If A uses anything from B inside its source, it should (generally speaking) include B itself. In the OP example, his header isn't using `cout`, and including `iostream` isn't a requisite (other than the `cout` that is being used in the main, unrelated to the include)

Comment: The most common is a header that declares but does not define a class type, and declares functions with arguments or return types that are pointers/references to that type. If the class itself does not rely on those functions, the header that defines the class also doesn't *need* to include the header that declares those functions. Except in rare cases (e.g. writing a function that accepts a pointer/reference that it forwards to another function) source files which call those functions need to instantiate the class, so must also include the header that defines the class.

Comment: It's a good example. I'd say C++ is "too raw" (include-wise) to say that there is a simplle standard after all. At least C++20 is supposed to fix this with modules

Comment: _"Every .cpp file is compiled separately"_, is completely fine and makes sense, but what if I just want to _"inject another file's content at that line"_, removing the need to include the same **indludes** in all the **cpp** files?

Comment: Whatb do you mean? When you write an include, you're already injecting the header's content there

Comment: @Iván Lets say I'm only interested in having a few functions in a separate file, called and wish to inject this into my main.cpp file. The functions rely on headers already included and dont wish to include them again. Can this be done as per the VERY BASIC example here [link]https://replit.com/@plisken1/demo1#main.cpp[link]

Comment: Yes, you can. But you shouldn't. Including the same file multiple times is not a problem. Every header usually have a guard: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-guards/